# Ansible when condition from debug msg

Tags: ansible, task, stdout

i want create a task of a when condition from a stdout.
Example here of playbook:

```
---
 - hosts: localhost
   gather_facts: false
   ignore_errors: yes
   vars:
     - dev_ip: '192.168.20.192'

   tasks:
    - name: checkking ssh status
      wait_for:
        host: "{{dev_ip}}"
        port: 22
        timeout: 2
        state: present
      register: ssh_stat

    - name: checkcondition
      debug:
        msg: "{{ssh_stat}}"
```

message out put is:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": false, 
        "elapsed": 2, 
        "failed": true, 
        "msg": "Timeout when waiting for 192.168.20.192:22"
    }
}
```

i want to make a when condition task if string "Timeout when waiting for 192.168.20.192:22" is in the ssh_stat.stdout

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: `ssh_stat.stdout` does not exist. `ssh_stat.msg` does.

Comment: Hi, am am just new into Ansible so my expertise are very low.
The ssh service were disabled on purpose to get that error, i want to execute a task with a when condition if the "Time out error" is present in the std.out.
ive tried different suggestion from the net but in some case i got an ('dic object' has no attribute' msg' when i use when: ssh_stat.stdout.find('Timeout when waiting') != -1

Comment: your ssh_stat.msg suggestion did work for me, maybe it can be improve a bit. now i get the error while evaluating conditional. now ive test it with when: ssh_stat.msg.find('Timeout when waiting') != -1

Comment: Please don't spread information needed to answer your question across comments: edit you question with your tries and explain what is going wrong. As a preliminary, you should read [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) in the help section to get more familiar with the site.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need:

```
---
- name: answer stack overflow
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  ignore_errors: yes

  tasks:
    - name: checkking ssh status
      wait_for:
        host: 192.168.1.23
        port: 22
        timeout: 2
        state: present
      register: ssh_stat
    - name: do something else when ssh_stat.msg == "Timeout when waiting for 192.168.1.23:22"
      shell: echo "I am doing it"
      when: ssh_stat.msg == "Timeout when waiting for 192.168.1.23:22"
```

output:

```
PLAY [answer stack overflow] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [checkking ssh status] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: Platform linux on host localhost is using the discovered Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python, but future installation of another Python interpreter could change this. See
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information.
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"}, "changed": false, "elapsed": 3, "msg": "Timeout when waiting for 192.168.1.23:22"}
...ignoring

TASK [do something else when ssh_stat.msg == "Timeout when waiting for 192.168.1.23:22"] ************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=1
```